# Creating new dictionary from existing dictionary after doing some calculation to values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following dictionary.

```
myD = {0: [1,2,3,4], 2: [2,3,4,5], 3: [3,4,5,6]}
```

and I need to create a new dictionary (or update current dictionary) by dividing values (list) using numbers in the following list

```
deviders = [2,4,8]
```

expected output (pseudo)- >

```
newD = {0: [1,2,3,4]/2, 2: [2,3,4,5]/4, 3: [3,4,5,6]/8}
```

Is there an elegant way to do this calculation and create a new dictionary?

Comment: Show your coding effort? Also what is the actual (non-psuedo) output desired?

Comment: you seem to rely on the order of the items in the dictionary which you should by no means do. How is `2` as a divider mapped to `[1,2,3,4]`?

Comment: So, with `[1,2,3,4]/2` you mean `[0.5, 1, 1.5, 2]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dictionary comprehension. First map your keys to division factors. Then divide each element in your list via list comprehensions.

```
div_map = {0: 2, 2: 4, 3: 8}
# or div_map = dict(zip(sorted(myD), (2, 4, 8)))

newD = {k: [i / div_map[k] for i in v] for k, v in myD.items()}
```

The syntax you are attempting is akin to 3rd party library NumPy:

```
import numpy as np

newD = {k: np.array(v) / div_map[k] for k, v in myD.items()}
```

Comment: how about `sort`ing the keys and `zip`ping them to the dividers?

Comment: Don't you think that numpy is kind of overkill here?

Comment: @SergeBallesta, I wouldn't say evil, but I just wanted to demonstrate OP's syntax isn't ridiculous, it's commonly used in operations far and wide (but not in pure Python).

Answer (score 4):

Given the staggered intervals between your keys, you can use something like the following:

```
from __future__ import division

d = {0: [1,2,3,4], 2: [2,3,4,5], 3: [3,4,5,6]}
dividers = [2,4,8]

new = dict((k, [i / j for i in d[k]]) for k, j in zip(sorted(d), dividers))

# {0: [0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0],
#  2: [0.5, 0.75, 1.0, 1.25],
#  3: [0.375, 0.5, 0.625, 0.75]}
```

In Python < 3.7, it might be a good idea to sort the keys of the dictionary because their order is not guaranteed to align with `dividers`.  That leads to needing to use `d[k]` instead of `.items()`/`.iteritems()` to iterate through the dictionary.

Comment: Would it be better (more Pythonic?) to iterate `for (k, v), d in zip(sorted(d.items()), dividers)`?

Comment: I am not sure @jpp.  Iterating over the dictionary (by name) iterates over the keys by default.  That's what I've always used.

Comment: Agreed, just a stylistic point, I often see `{k: foo(d[k]) for k in d}` instead of `{k: foo(v) for k, v in d.items()}`, always thought the latter is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on your question, hope it's of help;

```
def div(d, my_dict):
  count = 0
  for k, v in my_dict.items():
    my_dict[k] = [num/d[count] for num in v]
    count +=1
  return my_dict

myD = {0: [1,2,3,4], 2: [2,3,4,5], 3: [3,4,5,6]}
dividers = [2,4,8]
print(div(dividers, myD))
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you without any import and keeping the order of the keys:

```
myD = {0: [1,2,3,4], 2: [2,3,4,5], 3: [3,4,5,6]}     
dividers = [2,4,8]

result = {k: [v / dividers[ki]  for v in myD[k]] for ki,k in enumerate(sorted(myD.keys()))}

print(result)
# {0: [0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0], 2: [0.5, 0.75, 1.0, 1.25], 3: [0.375, 0.5, 0.625, 0.75]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `myD` is not longer than `deviders`, you have a single line way:

```
{ k: [ j / deviders[i] for j in myD[k] ] for i, k in enumerate(sorted(myD.keys())) }
```